# Deleting files in command prompt, using if and else

Tags: windows, batch-file

I currently need a batch script (Windows) that allows me to attempt to delete a file, and if it fails, perform another action:


    e.g.: del C:\test.bin

if fail attempt kill C:\test.bin

else echo Success

kill C:\test.bin

if success attempt del C:\test.bin

else echo Unable to kill process

Answer (score 2):

```
del "C:\test.bin" >nul 2>&1
if exist "C:\test.bin" (
    echo failed
) else (
    echo success
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of batch files, I suggest looking at the much more powerful [Power Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Comment: For such a trivial task? A bit overkill.